# Foursquare Checkin at a venue in iphone showing error 401,unauthorized. Why?

Tags: iphone, foursquare, checkin

I am trying foursquare integration in iphone. I am using the foursquare that is recommended and available in github.

1. I obtained my client_id and client_secret from fourquare site and replaced the value in constants.h file. (I also edited the foursquare profile for the api push notifications to enable checkin by my clients.)
2. I used it and got a list of venues close to me.
3. Then while I select a venue, I want myself to be checked in at that venue
4. But it checks and gives me the error 401, unauthorized.

Why is this happening? Am I missing anything? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I didn't call the function to get the oauth token. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: just take all the code that they have put in the sample code. it will work fine.